# How to check if the input string consists of a word matches with the information from API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Intended outcome: The user inputs any characters from the keyboard. They will then be used to check if the inputted string is a word from the Dictionary API. If they match with each other, the string will be in the `<p>` element. If not, then the inputted string will go through `anotherFunction()`.

Questions:

1. Is it possible by `keyboard.event`, but not in the `<input>` / `<textarea>`, for the `fetchApi()` to be able to search for a real word from a string, instead of each inputted character? (Like I do not want that only until the user types the word and press `Enter`, then the API starts kicking in)
2. If so, what can I change in the code in order to get the above intended outcome?

Thank you again, and again. Thanks a lot!

```
var characters = '';
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var word = result[arg0].word;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(input) {
  if (input.key >= 'a' && input.key <= 'z') {
    fetchApi(input.key);
  }
});

function fetchApi(word) {
  let url = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`;
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(result => data(result, word));
  }

function data(result, word) {
  if (input.key == word) {
      characters += input.key;
      text.innerHTML = characters;
  }
  else {
      text.innerHTML = anotherFunction();
  }
}
```

```
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right but I think what you want is:

1. Only listen for key events in the input field instead of the entire document. For this simply add the event listener to the desired `<input>` or `<textarea>` instead of the `document`. [Explained here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

```js
text.addEventListener('keydown', function(input) {
  if (input.key >= 'a' && input.key <= 'z') {
    fetchApi(input.key);
  }
});
```

2. You can also listen for the `Enter` key. For this you could either simply get the value of the `<input>` and send it directly to the API (`text.value`). **Or** if you want to filter the characters before (and change as little code as possible from your existing solution) you could also send your `characters` string to it. (Like the code below)

```js
let inputWord = ""
text.addEventListener('keydown', function(input) {
  if (input.key >= 'a' && input.key <= 'z') {
    inputWord += input.key; // add each character to string if it's between a-z
  } else if (input.key === "Enter") { // on enter fetch the entire inputWord
    fetchApi(inputWord);
    inputWord = "" // clear inputWord after Enter (but not in <input>)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the first question, I want exactly the document, instead of <input> or <textarea>.